# DBeaver import csv empty string as NULL is not working

Tags: postgresql, csv, dbeaver

I have the following table `prop_info` which has foreign key reference to `desp`. I am trying to import csv file which has these

```
prop_code,prop_name,price
ABC,,1.2,
ABB,Apple,5.0,
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE prop_info (
 prop_code CHAR (3) PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
 prop_name VARCHAR (100) REFERENCES desp (product_name) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 price float NOT NULL
);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE desp 
(
    product_name VARCHAR (100) PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
    product_desp VARCHAR (100)
);
```

I was trying to upload CSV using DBeaver, receiving this error:

> ERROR: insert or update on table "prop_info" violates foreign key constraint "prop_info_prop_name_fkey"
>   Detail: Key (prop_name)=() is not present in table "desp".

As per the PostgreSQL, I do have unquoted empty string.

> Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is \N
>   (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in CSV
>   format. You might prefer an empty string even in text format for cases
>   where you don't want to distinguish nulls from empty strings. This
>   option is not allowed when using binary format.

is this a issue with my DBeaver? Need help.

Comment: Show us your `copy` statement.

Comment: using the dbeaver import from csv function

Comment: Then the quote from the Postgres manual is irrelevant, as that applies to the `COPY` command. You need to check the options in DBeaver if you can tell it to treat an empty string as `NULL`

Answer (score 11):

There is an option *Set empty strings to NULL* which worked for me in DBeaver 21.3.4 Community Edition

[image]